# How do i make this print true or false if it finds a specific number?

Tags: java

I want to make a make a binarysearch to find a number in my 
       arraylist and print false or true if it gets found?

I want my targetValues to see if they exist in the arr list and print true or false

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        {

            int arr[] = {10,20,30,40};
        int targetValue[]= {10,25,40} 
        }

    }
```

this is my binary search code

```
    public static boolean binarySearch(int[] arr, int n) {
        int first = 0;
        int last = arr.length-1;
        int mid;
        while (first <= last){
            mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
            if (n == arr[mid]) return true;
            else if (n < arr[mid]) last = mid - 1;
            else first = mid + 1;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: I now it is legal to go without braces on your if/elses...but don't

Comment: Hint: loop over the target values, do a binary search for each of them and print the result.

Comment: It isn't hard finding  someone else binarySearch online. My teacher showed me that one on the powerpoint. And I have been trying different ways on writing it to understand it better. Later I will have to modify it so I can search for values in a textfile. So no I am not cheating.

Comment: Alright thanks for the input Thomas, Rob

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is sorted in ascending order, this should work:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            {
            int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
            int targetValue[] = {10, 25, 40};
            int index = 0;
            while (index < targetValue.length) {
                out.println("Search for " + targetValue[index] + " " + binarySearch(arr, targetValue[index]));
                index++;
            }

    }
    public static boolean binarySearch(int[] arr, int n) {
        int count = 0;
        int mid = (arr.length - 1) / 2;
        while (count < arr.length - 1) {
            if (n == arr[mid]) {
                return true;
            } else if (n < arr[mid]) {
                if (mid != 0) {
                    mid = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (mid != arr.length - 1) {
                    mid = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the function of [index] the only thing I dont really understand?